# Data Returning undefined with Meteor Router, Publish/Subscription

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs, publish-subscribe

```
    Meteor.publish('oneStory', function (postId) {  
    return Stories.find({ _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(postId) });
    });


    FlowRouter.route('/:postId', {  
      subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
        post = params.postId.toHexString;
        this.register('OneStory', Meteor.subscribe('oneStory', post));
      },
      action(params) {
        ReactLayout.render(FullStory, {content: {...params}});
      },

    });

FullStory = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData() {
    var data = {};
    // var postId = "ObjectId(\"".concat(this.props.content.postId);
    // postId = postId.concat("\")");


    data.story = Stories.findOne();


    return data;
  },

  render() {

    return (
     <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
       <h1>Testing</h1>
      </div>

    );
  }

});
```

I have a Mongo collection Stories. Whenever, I try Stories.findOne({}) it returns undefined and I am really confused why. I have tried doing Stories.findOne({}) where I pass in _id: postId but that also doesn't work. My hunch is that there is actually nothing being published, but I'm not sure why. Really lost, so any help would be greatly appreciated!